# Does cursor change count as a hover effect?

Tags: hover, accessibility

For ADA compliance I've read we should have more than one effect on hover. For example, only changing the color wouldn't be good enough for someone who is color blind, so adding an underline would help them.

Does the cursor change count towards one of the hover effect? I tried searching for that in a few different sites but I wasn't able to find the answer. Does anybody know?

Another example: would a hover effect which adds an underline and changes the cursor to the pointer be compliant on any of the WCAG levels (A, AA, AAA)?

Answer (score 1):

> For ADA compliance I've read we should have more than one effect on hover

I'd be interested to know where you read that.  WCAG, [the official accessibility guideline](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/), doesn't really say anything about hover effects.  It does say, [in 1.4.11](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#non-text-contrast),  that "[states](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#dfn-states)" must have sufficient contrast, and hover is an example of a state, so in that respect, WCAG does address the hover effect.  But nothing in WCAG requires a hover effect.

Now, if you're talking about [WCAG 1.4.1 Use of Color](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#use-of-color), there is a recommendation specific to anchor tags (`<a>`) that if a link is embedded in a paragraph, the link color must have at least a 3:1 contrast ratio with the paragraph color **and** an additional visual cue must be specified upon hover or focus, such as an underline.  You can see the full text in [G183](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G183).

So it's tough to answer the question about a cursor hover effect until I fully understand what you're trying to do and which sources you're using for your information.

A best practice is that any hover effect you implement should also be available upon focus too.  This is typically done in CSS by having the `:hover` and `:focus` point to the same rules in the CSS.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. Yes, the "additional visual cue upon hover" is what I'm referring to; the recommendation for a [non-color designator](https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/link_text) (near the bottom of the page in the WCAG 2 Note box). Sometimes my boss says he doesn't want an underline on hover so I was wondering if changing the cursor to a pointer, along with a color change, would be sufficient?

Comment: G183 (https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G183.html) also talks about links.  All it says is an additional visual cue should be used.  If that additional cue is also color based, then you'd still have a problem.  You could make it bold or italic instead of underline.  A cursor change upon hover is ok for mouse users.  What happens when you TAB to the link?  If you don't have an underline and you can't do a cursor shape, what's your backup plan?

Comment: When you mentioned "A cursor change upon hover is ok for mouse users. What happens when you TAB to the link?" it helped me understand. If you can please update your answer with that or something similar then I'll accept it as the solution. Thanks.